# linux bash scripting to remove certain text

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

i have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ALL HTML FILES
FILES="*.html"
# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
INF="$f"
OUTF="$f.out.tmp"
# replace javascript
sed '/<!--fff309/,/<!--\/fff309-->/d' $INF > $OUTF
/bin/cp $OUTF $INF
/bin/rm -f $OUTF
done
```

the html is look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>some normal html code</div><!--fff309-->some javascript code goes here... <!--/fff309-->

<div>
some other html....
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the bash script work, however it remove all the html part below the `<!--/fff309-->`

so it become:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>some normal html code</div>
```

is there anyway to do so that it only remove the part:

```
<!--fff309--> ...  <!--/fff309-->
```

Thanks

Comment: That `sed` script works fine on my system (with GNU sed version 4.2.1). What does `sed --version` report on your system?

Comment: Also OK on Mac OS X (BSD non-GNU, there is no `-version` or `--version`

Comment: sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: this is my OS:
Linux abc.com 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: have you tried adding `-e` after `sed`?

Comment: @Redbox as you are using the same version of @ruak it should work. You could execute your script with `-x` to see what happens but I suspect the error is not in the `sed` command

Comment: added -e not working trying -x now

Comment: try using `-i`, instead of creating a temporary file, and doing copies and removes after the process; `-i` on sed provides inplace substitutions.

Comment: i directly run the command like this:
sed -i '/<!--fff309/,/<!--\/fff309-->/d' index.html
it does remove all other part below it.

Comment: As per the file you posted, both the markers are in the same line, not in different lines.. You could simply use: sed '/<!--fff309-->/d' $INF > $OUTF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use perl inplace replacement for this as below:
i had changed your script as below to make it more simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ALL HTML FILES
FILES="*.html"
# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/\<\!--fff309--\>/.../\<\!--\/fff309--\>/)' $f
done
```

Main task is done by the line:

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/\<\!--fff309--\>/.../\<\!--\/fff309--\>/)'
```

This does change the file directly witout having a need to create a temporary file.
I testted it and the command works for me.

Also if you insist on using sed  the below works for me:

```
sed '/\<\!--fff309--\>/,/\<\!--\/fff309--\>/d' your_file
```

for your case it would be better to use `-i` option of sed which does in place replacement as below.

```
sed -i '/\<\!--fff309--\>/,/\<\!--\/fff309--\>/d' your_file
```

so using this your script will be changed to as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ALL HTML FILES
FILES="*.html"
# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
sed '/\<\!--fff309--\>/,/\<\!--\/fff309--\>/d' $f
done
```

After looking at the HTML file:

this is the thing that you need:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\<\!--fff309--\>.*\<\!--\/fff309--\>//g' your_file
```

so your script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ALL HTML FILES
FILES="*.html"
# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
perl -pi -e 's/\<\!--fff309--\>.*\<\!--\/fff309--\>//g' $f
done
```

Comment: same problem, it remove all the text below it.. check the original html here: http://pastebin.com/jpLf5L7j

Comment: sed -i '/\<\!--fff309--\>/,/\<\!--\/fff309--\>/d' does not remove anynthing.. but this will:
sed -i '/<\!--fff309-->/,/<\!--\/fff309-->/d' however it remove all part below it.

Comment: I checked your html file.i see both FFF309's are in the same line.but your question says that they are on different lines.So change your question.i am downvoting your question since it is wrongly framed.And this is the reason why all the lines below the first find of FFF309 will be removed with the regex.

Comment: sorry, i dont know about that.. what is the solution for that? i just want that part to be removed

Comment: Bingo! now it work fine.. do you know how to loop all the subdirectory?

Comment: Change your for loop to <for f in `find . -name "*.html`>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on your sed, but in your bash script.
Remove the double quotes from "*.html".

Bash consider double quoted strings as an unique string, i. e., it won't separate the string using the value of IFS, neither expand your wildcards, avoiding, thus, the `f` variable on your script to be simply a `<name>.html`, and forcing it to be `*.html`.

If you echo the different results, you'll notice that, with double quotes, the variable `f` will be `*.html`, and when you echo it, the expansion will be performed, so that you'll have: `<name_1>.html <name_2>.html ... <name_n>.html`.

For example,

- create two or more `.html` files in your directory;
- execute the following script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  echo "Incorrect:"    
  for i in "*.html"; do
      echo $i;
  done

  echo "Correct:"
  for i in *.html; do
      echo $i;
  done
  ```

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ALL HTML FILES
FILES=*.html
# for loop read each file
for f in $FILES
do
INF=$f
OUTF=$f.out.tmp
# replace javascript
sed '/<!--fff309/,/<!--\/fff309-->/d' $INF > $OUTF
/bin/cp $OUTF $INF
/bin/rm -f $OUTF
done
```

Comment: i removed. now become this: FILES=*.html, still got the same problem

Comment: have you tried to use `*.html` directly in the script, just to check if the problem persists

Comment: @Redbox I've tried to rewrite the .sh, with alterations; see my edit.

Comment: your code work, but it still remove all part below the <!--/fff309-->

Comment: edited the question, the fff309 part is same line. sorry if that cause the problem?